# Hadoop on Virtual machine

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am trying to work and experiment with Hadoop and map reduce. For this purpose I am running Hadoop on single node cluster on virtual machine provided by the yahoo and making code through eclipse. I just want to know what can be the limitation or disadvantages of running hadoop on virtual machine or it is advisable to start working with isolated installation of Hadoop from the start.

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 0):

You can run Hadoop on Virtual machine for learning purpose, But not recommended for production or performance testing
As Hadoop runs on cluster of machines, it takes advantage of multiple nodes' hardware, Hadoop is used / designed to process huge volume of data, for that purpose we need more computing units (CPU) and more Memory (RAM) and it wont be efficient on virtual machine.

But Yes if you want to learn Hadoop and test you can use virtual machines